# Using Python to enter data into form and get data from results page

Tags: python, web, mechanize

I am using Python 2.7 on a 32 bit Windows machine.

I am trying to enter species data into http://explorer.natureserve.org and retrieve the results, but am having difficulty understanding how to do it. Needless to say I am relatively new to Python.

I have the following code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://explorer.natureserve.org")
assert "NatureServe" in driver.title
SciName = driver.find_element_by_name('searchSciOrCommonName')
SciName.send_keys("Arabis georgiana")
SciName.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) 
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
```

The above works, but now I need to select the element `Arabis georgiana` on the results page, which will take me to another page. How do I get the results page back into Python and redirect to the page that I actually want?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `searchSciOrCommonName` field value this way:

```
br.form = list(br.forms())[0]
br.form['searchSciOrCommonName'] = 'butterfly'
response = br.submit()
```

Then, you can parse the HTML response via, for example, [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

for item in soup.select('table[border="1"] > tr i')[1:]:
    print(item.text.strip())
```

which would print:

```
Aglais io
Callophrys mossii hidakupa
Callophrys mossii marinensis
Cercyonis pegala incana
...
Psora nipponica
Flowering Plants
Asclepias tuberosa
```